# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' cuando Añado Onclick

Tags: javascript, html

He leído todas las preguntas sugeridas y no encuentro la contestación a este error. Tengo tres archivos haciendo un programa simple HTML/JavaScript.

```js
var currentPlayer = "O"
function place(box) {
    if(box.innerText != "") return;
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer == "O" ? currentPlayer = "X": currentPlayer = "O";
    //Box 1
    if(box.id == "0_0"){
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_0","2_0");
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_1","2_2");
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_0","2_0");
    }
    //Box 2
    if(box.id == "1_0"){
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_0","2_0");
        checkGameBoard("1_0","1_1","1_2");
    }
    //Box 3
    if(box.id == "2_0"){
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_0","2_0");
        checkGameBoard("2_0","1_1","0_2");
        checkGameBoard("2_0","2_1","2_2");
    }
    //Box 4
    if(box.id == "0_1"){
        checkGameBoard("0_1","1_1","2_1");
        checkGameBoard("0_0","0_1","0_2");
    }
    //Box 5
    if(box.id == "1_1"){
        checkGameBoard("0_0","1_1","2_2");
        checkGameBoard("1_0","1_1","1_2");
        checkGameBoard("2_0","1_1","0_2");
        checkGameBoard("0_1","1_1","2_1");
    }
     //Box 6
     if(box.id == "2_1"){
        checkGameBoard("0_1","1_1","2_1");
        checkGameBoard("2_0","2_1","2_2");
    }
    //Box 7
    if(box.id == "0_2"){
        checkGameBoard("0_0","0_1","0_2");
        checkGameBoard("0_2","1_1","2_0");
        checkGameBoard("0_2","1_2","2_2");
    }
    //Box 8
    if(box.id == "1_2"){
        checkGameBoard("0_2","1_2","2_2");
        checkGameBoard("1_0","1_1","1_2");
    }
    //Box 9
    if(box.id == "2_2"){
        checkGameBoard("0_2","1_2","2_2");
        checkGameBoard("2_2","1_1","0_0");
        checkGameBoard("2_0","2_1","2_2");
    }
}
function checkGameBoard(firstCoord,secondCoord,thirdCoord) {
    var first = document.getElementById(firstCoord).innerText;
    var second = document.getElementById(secondCoord).innerText;
    var thrid = document.getElementById(thirdCoord).innerText;
    if(first == "") return;
        if(first == second && first == thrid){
            alert("Winner!")
        }
}
//+ attacks a random adjacent oppenent peice ÷ trades places with random adjacent opopnet * places a second copy on empty adjacent square
var noughts = ["O", "O+","O-", "O/", "O*"]
var crosses = ["X", "X+", "X÷", "X*"]

function showOptions() {  
    document.getElementById("Player1").innerHTML = "";
    for(i=0; i<noughts.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("Player1").innerHTML += "<input type='button' value='"+ noughts[i] + "' onclick='chooseThis('" + noughts[i] + "')>";
        // alert(document.getElementById("Player1").innerHTML)
    }
}

function chooseThis(item) {
     currentPlayer = item;
     alert(item);
 }
```

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 98vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: none;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.row div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Player1">
        <input type="button" value="Ready Player One?" id="PlayerOne" onclick="showOptions()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Si elimino el atributo de `onclick` trabaja bien. Sin embargo cuando uso el atributo recibo el mensaje de unexpected token. He tratado de dividir la sentencia en secciones mas pequeñas pero recibo el mismo error.

Comment: Recuerda que si la respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla con la palomita debajo de las flechas de la respuesta para indicar que fue resuelta el problema.

Comment: Esta herramienta me ayuda mucho, espero que te sirva: https://jshint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que estás concatenando un valor para generar un elemento, deberás indicar que es una cadena de texto para evitar el error de sintáxis (prestar atención al parámetro en la llamada a la función `chooseThis()`).

Ejemplificando, tu código actual queda:

```
<input type="button" value="O-" onclick="chooseThis(O-)">
```

Y el corregido es:

```
<input type="button" value="O-" onclick="chooseThis('O-')">
```

```js
var currentPlayer = 'O'
function place(box) {
    if(box.innerText != '') return;
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer == 'O' ? currentPlayer = 'X': currentPlayer = 'O';
    //Box 1
    if(box.id == '0_0'){
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_0','2_0');
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_1','2_2');
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_0','2_0');
    }
    //Box 2
    if(box.id == '1_0'){
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_0','2_0');
        checkGameBoard('1_0','1_1','1_2');
    }
    //Box 3
    if(box.id == '2_0'){
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_0','2_0');
        checkGameBoard('2_0','1_1','0_2');
        checkGameBoard('2_0','2_1','2_2');
    }
    //Box 4
    if(box.id == '0_1'){
        checkGameBoard('0_1','1_1','2_1');
        checkGameBoard('0_0','0_1','0_2');
    }
    //Box 5
    if(box.id == '1_1'){
        checkGameBoard('0_0','1_1','2_2');
        checkGameBoard('1_0','1_1','1_2');
        checkGameBoard('2_0','1_1','0_2');
        checkGameBoard('0_1','1_1','2_1');
    }
     //Box 6
     if(box.id == '2_1'){
        checkGameBoard('0_1','1_1','2_1');
        checkGameBoard('2_0','2_1','2_2');
    }
    //Box 7
    if(box.id == '0_2'){
        checkGameBoard('0_0','0_1','0_2');
        checkGameBoard('0_2','1_1','2_0');
        checkGameBoard('0_2','1_2','2_2');
    }
    //Box 8
    if(box.id == '1_2'){
        checkGameBoard('0_2','1_2','2_2');
        checkGameBoard('1_0','1_1','1_2');
    }
    //Box 9
    if(box.id == '2_2'){
        checkGameBoard('0_2','1_2','2_2');
        checkGameBoard('2_2','1_1','0_0');
        checkGameBoard('2_0','2_1','2_2');
    }
}
function checkGameBoard(firstCoord,secondCoord,thirdCoord) {
    var first = document.getElementById(firstCoord).innerText;
    var second = document.getElementById(secondCoord).innerText;
    var thrid = document.getElementById(thirdCoord).innerText;
    if(first == '') return;
        if(first == second && first == thrid){
            alert('Winner!')
        }
}
//+ attacks a random adjacent oppenent peice ÷ trades places with random adjacent opopnet * places a second copy on empty adjacent square
var noughts = ['O', 'O+','O-', 'O/', 'O*']
var crosses = ['X', 'X+', 'X÷', 'X*']

function showOptions() {  
    document.getElementById('Player1').innerHTML = '';
    for(i=0; i<noughts.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('Player1').innerHTML += '<input type="button" value="'+ noughts[i] + '" onclick="chooseThis(\'' + noughts[i] + '\')">';
        // alert(document.getElementById('Player1').innerHTML)
    }
}

function chooseThis(item) {
     currentPlayer = item;
     alert(item);
 }
```

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 98vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: none;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.row div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="0_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="1_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
        <div id="2_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Player1">
        <input type="button" value="Ready Player One?" id="PlayerOne" onclick="showOptions()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Asi que el \' define texto? onclick="chooseThis(\'' + noughts[i] + '\')">' Tambien usaste apostrofe (') solo para afuera y signo de cita (') adentro. Hay alguna regla que require este sintaxis o es preferencia. ¡Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: @GabeRuiz Respondiendo a tu pregunta, te recomiendo la siguiente lectura con relación a HTML: [¿Comillas dobles o comillas simples en HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/223709/729) y con relación a javascript, es es cuestión de que estilo emplees, yo te recomiendo la [guía de estilo de Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) donde ahí mismo y muchos otros lados más, recomiendan comillas simples ([Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-strings-use-single-quotes), [ejemplos ReactJs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), etc).