# ¿Comillas dobles o comillas simples en HTML?

Tags: html

Personalmente me gusta utilizar comillas dobles sobre atributos/valores del HTML, pero he visto códigos donde el uso de la comillas simples es lo que predomina sobre el documento ¡e incluso! algunos con ausencia de comillas.

```
<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type='text' name='age' />
<input type=text name=age />
```

Fuera de saber la compatibilidad de su uso hay con navegadores, me gustaría conocer ¿cuál de esas formas usar y por qué? ¿hay alguna implicación funcional que afecte el rendimiento?

**Ejemplo:**

En muchos lenguajes de programación; la diferencia entre comillas simples y dobles para declarar las cadenas de texto, es la interpolación, pero está demás discutir eso sobre HTML pues sabemos no entra en dicha categoría. Pero ¿existe algún comportamiento que altere la forma de presentar los datos?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Resumen

Se utilizan comillas dobles ya que en los inicios del lenguaje de etiquetado ([SGML](http://www.hipertexto.info/documentos/sgml.htm)), los autores podían hacer uso de caracteres especiales (que eran a veces difíciles de introducir, si no es que imposibles a través del teclado) con solo escribir su referencia, p. ej.:

- `"&amp;lt;"` representa el signo `<`.
- `"&amp;gt;"` representa el signo `>`.
- `"&amp;quot;"` representa el signo `"`.
- `"&amp;#229;"` (en decimal) representa la letra `a` con un pequeño círculo sobre ella.
- Entre otros...

En pocas palabras, al igual que algunos lenguajes de programación, gozaban de una funcionalidad enriquecida a comparación de las comillas simples.

Fuente: [W3C - HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

---

### Explicación

El [documento oficial de la W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes) (sobre sintáxis HTML5) marca que es perfectamente correcto el uso de la pareja atributo-valor con comillas simples, comillas dobles o incluso con ausencia de comillas; ¡claro! cada uno con ciertas reglas.

#### Valor del atributo sin comillas

> El nombre del atributo, seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido de un único caracter U+300D EQUAL SIGN (signo de igual), seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido del valor del atributo, el cuál, adicional a los requerimiento brindados..., deberá prescindir de cualquier [caracter de espacio](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-characters) literal, de cualquier U+0022 QUOTATION MARK (comillas simples), U+0027 APOSTROPHE (apostrofe), U+003D EQUALS SIGN (símbolo de igual), U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN (menor que), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (mayor que) o U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT (acento grave), y no deberá ser una cadena vacía.

#### Valor del atributo con comillas simples

> El nombre del atributo, seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido de un único caracter U+300D EQUAL SIGN (signo de igual), seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido de U+0027 APOSTROPHE (apostrofe), seguido del valor del atributo, el cuál, adicional a los requerimiento brindados..., deberá prescindir de cualquier caracter de U+0027 APOSTROPHE (apostrofe literal) y finalmente seguido de otro U+0027 APOSTROPHE (apostrofe).

#### Valor del atributo con comillas dobles

> El nombre del atributo, seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido de un único caracter U+300D EQUAL SIGN (signo de igual), seguido de uno o más caracteres de espacio, seguido de U+0022 QUOTATION MARK (comilla inglesa), seguido del valor del atributo, el cuál, adicional a los requerimiento brindados..., deberá prescindir de cualquier caracter de U+0022 QUOTATION MARK (comilla inglesa) y finalmente seguido de otra U+0022 QUOTATION MARK (comilla inglesa).

---

Derivado de todo ello (y probablemente la costumbre) la W3C utiliza en sus [ejemplos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#configuring-a-form-to-communicate-with-a-server) las comillas dobles o sin comillas, es por comodidad y en ocasiones buenas prácticas promover aquello mismo que la documentación oficial te insta a hacer a base de sus ejemplos, hacer lo contrario es como tratar de talar un árbol, yendo en contra de la veta de la madera.